# Size of my IOS App

Tags: ios, audio, appstore-approval

I have developed an iPhone app that uses a lot of audio files. 
I think my application is expected to reach approximately 200 MB in size. 
There are issues with the approval of the application? 
The audio files are present inside my application directory MyApplication.app /. Is this correct or should it be moved within the Documents directory? 
Thank you all, 
Vincenzo

Comment: I think you should use server because as you can read in App Store Review Guidelines:  2.15 Apps larger than 100MB in size will not download over cellular networks (this is automatically prohibited by the App Store). But you shouldn't use documents folder for download. you should use cache.

Comment: I think the only solution is the one that you suggested ... the problem is where can I find a free remote server? Do you have any suggestions? 
The download file must be within the AppDelegate or do I make a UIViewController with a fake picture and I download files?

Comment: you can use google drive, dropbox, etc. for that you can download  their sdk with samples. i prefer google drive.

Comment: Thank you so much ... but to download the audio file I can do within the app delegate or do I have to do a main screen?

Comment: you should use vendor's framework. all work makes in background. i mean without ui.

Comment: you can use view controller or other controllers for the downloading

Comment: I can not do it in the background because my application contains common phrases that are translated into Russian ... such as "Hello", "How are you?" 
Each phrase has a sound file in Russian ... I'm forced to do so when I start the application.

Comment: you can play phrase when download has finished. and you can keep all phrases in cache and play from there. you can make download at first start application.

Comment: I would like to download all the sentences start of the application and save the Documents folder but I want to do when you start the application because in Italy the cellular data network is not good and I would like that my application can only be used when the its inception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**There is absolutely no problem** in submitting an app with size 200 MB or more. There are games that weigh more than a Gigabyte. I submitted an app in the past that weighted 250 MB. So that shouldn't be any problem for the approval.

Unless you have something fishy there (e.g. audios that won't ever get played in the app, etc.), there is no problem with the app approval in this sense.
As someone already estated your app may only be downloaded, once approved, over Wifi or through the iTunes desktop application, but not through cellular data plans. But that is another matter.

Ah! And you may keep all the audios in the Application folder as long as they are not going to be changed since the moment the app is compiled (ie, they are read-only files).

Comment: Hello, 
I am very pleased to read what you have written. 
So you say that there are no problems if my application dovessere be about 200 MB? 
thanks

Comment: Hi @macuser as I said, there is no problem with the reviewers if your app weighs more than 200 MB.

Comment: Hi @macuser if you find the answer correct, please consider accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, 
I found your very good solution but I have not put the best answer because I have to understand what is the most correct ... if you download data from the cloud / ftp or if you leave them in the application

Comment: Hi! That was not the question. Whether you should leave the audios inside the app or not, that is another question. A very interesting one, but it is not a technical one but a "political" one. I think you should ask that question as another one.

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your audio files somewhere on server and can download at the application launch and can use them whenever download is complete.

Comment: I think the only solution is the one that you suggested ... the problem is where can I find a free remote server? Do you have any suggestions? 
The download file must be within the AppDelegate or do I make a UIViewController with a fake picture and I download files?

Comment: You can make controller as per requirements and can be uploaded on dropbox and many other cloud products

Answer (score 1):

An app may be up to 2 GB in size, according to Apple. If the app is larger than 100 MB it cannot be downloaded over cellular network, however, it might be downloaded over WiFi or through iTunes. When it comes to the approval, nobody knows for sure. If you have a lot of audio files that will be used only in rare cases for a very limited amount of users, Apple **might** complain that you add a lot of data that is not very relevant for the vast majority, however, the size of the app itself should not be a problem.

Comment: I have an application consisting of about 1100 audio files in the Russian language this because I currently have more than 1100 phrases within my application. 
I think that eventually I will use Dropbox because it seemed the best solution ...